# Where is the File's Owner in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to find where the File's Owner in Xcode 8 is... I'm trying to connect a label object and a button object to it. All I can find is old resources from Xcode 4 where the File's Owner was easy to locate.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In NIB or storyboard? NIBs use "file owner", but storyboards don't.

Comment: @Rob, Sorry for the lack of information provided. I'm talking here about storyboard. So if storyboard doesn't use "file owner", how can I connect my two objects? Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to connect label and button to the view controller, you specify the view controller base class for the scene, and then you select the assistant editor and drag from the control in IB to the source code in the assistant editor. The notion of "file owner" doesn't make sense in storyboard, because the storyboard references multiple scenes, each with its own base class.

Comment: Here is the code:

Comment: I bet it you google "iOS storyboard tutorial" or something like that, you'll see lots of examples.

Comment: Got it to work, thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 3):

- In a *xib* file, the file's owner is still there.
- In a *storyboard* file, the view controller of a scene is the file's owner for that scene.

Answer (score 1):

file owner is not there storyboard's it is only present in xib/nib views

```
you connect buttons labels like this,
```

[image: storyboard]

```
    you already know the old methods of connecting the 
labels in xib files, xcode 8 also supports previous implementations
```

[image: xibfiles]